# opencv visual studio 2005 exception (windows 7 32 bit)

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2005

please can anybody help me please I'm suffering every time i debug my project i have this exception and i cant solve it please help what is causing this exception and how can i solve it.
this my code:

```
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This is a simple, introductory OpenCV program. 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#define PIXEL(img,x,y) (img)->imageData[x*img->widthStep+y]


/**
 * Replacement for Matlab's bwareaopen()
 * Input image must be 8 bits, 1 channel, black and white (objects)
 * with values 0 and 255 respectively
 */
/*void removeSmallBlobs(cv::Mat& im, double size)
{
    // Only accept CV_8UC1
    if (im.channels() != 1 || im.type() != CV_8U)
        return;

    // Find all contours
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    cv::findContours(im.clone(), contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        // Calculate contour area
        double area = cv::contourArea(contours[i]);

        // Remove small objects by drawing the contour with black color
        if (area > 0 && area <= size)
            cv::drawContours(im, contours, i, CV_RGB(0,0,0), -1);
    }
}


*/




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    IplImage *Img, *img;

    int height,width;
    int i,j, count=0;
    int morph_elem=0;
    int morph_size = 0;
    int morph_operator = 0;
    //read image
    Img = cvLoadImage("1.jpg",1);
    cvShowImage("original image",Img );

    //RGB to HSV 
    IplImage* hsv = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(Img), 8, 3 );
    cvCvtColor( Img, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV );
    cvShowImage("hsv image ",hsv );
    //extract the h, s, and v images individualy
    IplImage* h_plane = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(Img), 8, 1 );
    IplImage* s_plane = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(Img), 8, 1 );
    IplImage* v_plane = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(Img), 8, 1 );
    IplImage* planes[] = { h_plane, s_plane };
    cvCvtPixToPlane( hsv, h_plane, s_plane, v_plane, 0 );


    // Now apply each color band's particular thresholds to the color band
    IplImage* yellow = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(v_plane), 8, 3 );
     cvThreshold( h_plane, h_plane,0.09*255,0.14*255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);
     cvThreshold( s_plane, s_plane,0.1*255,1.0*255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);
     cvThreshold( v_plane, v_plane,0.1*255,1.0*255,CV_THRESH_BINARY);
     cvShowImage("h mask ",h_plane );
     cvShowImage("s mask ",s_plane );
     cvShowImage("v mask ",v_plane );

      CvMat *h_array = cvCreateMat(h_plane->height,h_plane->width,CV_8UC1 );
      CvMat *s_array = cvCreateMat(s_plane->height,s_plane->width,CV_8UC1 );
      CvMat *v_array= cvCreateMat(v_plane->height,v_plane->width,CV_8UC1 );
       cvConvert( h_plane, h_array );
        cvConvert( s_plane,s_array );
         cvConvert( v_plane,v_array );


    // Anding
    CvMat* yellowObjectsMask= cvCreateMat( Img->height,Img->width,CV_8UC1 );
    cvAnd(h_array, s_array,yellowObjectsMask);
    cvShowImage("yellow objects ",yellowObjectsMask );
    cvShowImage("yellow objects ",yellowObjectsMask );

//convert to IplImage
    //IplImage *im = cvLoadImage( "1.jpg");
    //CvMat *mat = cvCreateMat(im->height,im->width,CV_32FC3 ); 
     //cvConvert( im,mat );


/*int count=0;

for (int i=0;i<yellowObjectsMask->rows;i++){
    for int j=0;j<yellowObjectsMask->cols;j++){
        if (yellowObjectsMask(i,j)==0){
           count=count+1;
        }

    }
}
if (count==i*j){
       cout<<"not infected"; 
}

  */





    // wait for a key
    cvWaitKey(0);

    // release the images and close the windows
    cvReleaseImage(&Img );
    //cvDestroyWindow("Output");
    //cvDestroyWindow("Gray");


    return 0;
}
```

---

Unhandled exception at 0x75ba9617 in FirstProj.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0011fb38..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's path error which caused the exception